# Uncaught TypeError: {(intermediate value)} is not a function

Tags: reactjs

I'm receiving the **"Uncaught TypeError: {(intermediate value)} is not a function"** over this line;

**export default connect( mapStateToProps, { fetchSurveys }(SurveyList));**

But cannot understand what is wrong on it

Comment: You're calling `{ fetchSurveys }` as a function, which it is not (it's an object). You forgot to close the call to `connect` after `{ fetchSurveys }`.

Comment: Thanks so much, still learning React ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The part `{ fetchSurveys }(SurveyList)` creates a new object an tries to call it, but objects are not functions and cannot be called to, this causes an error.